# Problems with Material-UI components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm trying to use the http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer (Docked Example) component from Material-UI with ReactJS.

I get error an error on the "=" in the following line:

```
handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
```

I get the same error on some other components as well. I'm using the latest version of Material-UI.

Same with this one: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table (Complex Example) on the following code:

```
handleToggle = (event, toggled) => {
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: The error is on the first "=".

Comment: Are you using ES6 throughout?  What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I just had to add "stage-0" to my loaders and install "babel-preset-stage-0". Now everything works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to use an ES6 transpiler such as babel to convert your code to JS that current browsers can understand, or not use fat-arrow functions:

```
handleToggle() {
  this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
};
```