# How to properly use typescript module augmentation for material-ui components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have read the existing answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544124/problems-with-material-ui-components) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588850/definitelytyped-add-new-props-typing-for-existing-component), but they seem to be outdated.

I have tried the following to augment the type definition for the button component, both in a separate typings file (.d.ts) and in the react component itself, but to no avail.

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/Button" {
  export interface ButtonProps {
    to?: string;  
  }
}
```

When put in the separate .d.ts file, I get a 'JSX element type 'Button' does not have any construct or call signatures.' error.

If put in the same file as the component itself, compiler just complains that property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps & { children?: ReactNode; }' as if nothing was defined at all.

So I'm wondering about the current correct way to augment component type definitions in material-ui (v3.0.2).

Thank you & Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ButtonProps` interface is actually declared in the `@material-ui/core/Button/Button` module.  The following code in your component file should work:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/Button/Button" {
  export interface ButtonProps {
    to?: string;  
  }
}
```

Comment: How to name/locate file where to put this piece of code?

Comment: You should be able to put it directly into a react component file or in a separate .d.ts file, importing the augmented interface first, i.e. `import { ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core/Button"`

Comment: It doesn't work for `Link` for some reason :) apparently it's a different reason - `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.` so thanks for the quick answer :)